Entity Framework Core is slow when executing the first query
I am using Entity Framework Core for the first time, and I'm getting quite confused trying to understand why is it going too slow (about 2-3 seconds) performing the first query every time I start-up my project.
To give you extra information I can say that I am working on a .NET 6 project and the version of the EF framework is 7.0.18 as it is the last version compatible with my .NET version.
Here is the method I am calling to execute the query:
public async Task<string> GetField()
{
    using ContextClass context = new ContextClass();

    var variable = await context.Table
                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(v => v.Id == 429719);

    return variable?.Field ?? "a"; //If nothing is found, it will retrieve an empty string
}

What I could see is that if I call the same method (or another one from another DataContext it won't take these seconds again and the result will be returned immediately.
The solution I found for the moment is creating an "Initializer" class which does the following:
public class Initializer
{
    public Initializer() { }

    public async void DbInitializer()
    {
        using (var context = new CodisContext())
        {
            await context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();
        }
    }
}

Calling the DbInitializer function makes the first query running as it is expected to.
Do you have any tip or advice to avoid using this method?

EF deals with entities, not tables. DbContext is a multi-entity Unit-of-Work, not a database connection. What are you connecting to? Is the database up? Does it even exist? If you target an infrequently used Azure SQL or AWS RDS the database may be down due to inactivity. The first connection actually starts the database. When you call context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync you're actually telling EF to make an ADO.NET connection to that database and ensure it's up. The connection, not the check, starts the database

In general, cold starts are an issue for every web application. The first time a database starts the server buffers will be empty, which means the first calls will be slower. The same goes for in-memory caches. In a server farm, adding a "cold" web server to the farm would result in overall delays as the requests sent to that server would take longer. To solve this deployment tools execute warmup scripts to force the server to load data in its cache and buffers

There's a lot more going on within the context of first query executed by EF. It has a ton of housekeeping to do, starting with model building. If you look at the debug window - if you are using VS [Code] - you'll see it loading dynamically generated assemblies sometimes.

P.S. Your EnsureCreatedAsync() call will fail if the user connecting to the database - which should be separate for the application, all on its own - does not have database creation rights. This user should not have DDL rights, in general.

How many Entities in your DbContext? EF Core can be slow on first run until finishing build big Model completely.

Side note, that's a very expensive way of getting only one value from the database.

Now responding to @PanagiotisKanavos. The DB is up and exist since I am connecting to my work SQL Server. I supposed that the EnsureCreatedAsync method was just a check to make sure the DB is up, but anyway, is it OK for establishing a first connection and avoid the slowness? Or it has to be a query?

@TanveerBadar what do you mean by "which should be separate for the application" referring to the user who connect to the DB? How should I separate it? Maybe i'm not understanding it.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv it's just a test, but the Context only initializes one DbSet.

@GertArnold I see, it was an example that I took from a Microsoft forum

@Rau18 those are discussion forums, not tutorials or references. What you tried loads the entire object in memory, equivalent to SELECT * From Customer where ID=123. That's slow, especially if the table contains large fields. To get just the name, you'd use context.Customers.Where(c=>c.Id=123).Select(c=>.Name).FirstOrDefault(); which generates SELECT Name from Customer Where ID=123.

@Rau18 there's a related GH issue which explains why the delay occurs, how to force the initialization early without even connecting to the database and refers to compiled models for big models (100s of entities). For small models early initialization is enough

First of all, EF deals with entities, not tables. This isn't semantics, especially in this case.
The DbContext model is initialized the first time it's used (not created), using the entity metadata for the entities defined as DbSet properties, attribute metadata and the Fluent API. The DbContext doesn't connect to the database to do this, because it only cares about the entities, not the tables. EnsureCreatedAsync(), DbContext.Add or executing a query require a model and so force the initialization.
To avoid delays you can force initialization at startup with eg:
public void DbInitializer()
{
    using (var context = new CodisContext())
    {
        context.Add(new Customer(..));
    }
}

This snippet doesn't even open a connection to the database. Nothing is loaded and SaveChanges isn't called so there's nothing to persist.
This is mentioned in a Github issue, Slow First Query after project startup. This is normal because the first time the DbContext is created, all the entity metadata has to be computed and cached, and the code has to be JITed. As Shay Rojansky (the maintainer of NpgSQL and EF team member) answers :

the first query being slow is a very natural state of affairs; you'll find the same effect even in non-database-related functionailty, simply because code has to be JITted, caches warmed up, etc. The typical way to achieve fast first query is to trigger a query (or at least model building) as part of your application startup, i.e. not expose your server to users until it has already been "warmed up"
Having said that, the new compiled models feature can reduce your startup time for large models; but there will still be a possibly significant gap between the very first query and the second one.

Compiled models are used to speed up initialization for large models (hundreds or thousands of entities). The model is initialized the first time it needs to be used, not when the DbContext is created. From the docs:

Startup time here is the time to perform the first operation on a DbContext when that DbContext type is used for the first time in the application. Note that just creating a DbContext instance does not cause the EF model to be initialized. Instead, typical first operations that cause the model to be initialized include calling DbContext.Add or executing the first query.

A compiled model is created from the command line with :
dotnet ef dbcontext optimize

You need to tell EF to use a compiled model with the UseModel call:
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder
        .UseModel(MyCompiledModels.BlogsContextModel.Instance)
        .UseSqlite(@"Data Source=test.db");


The first query against the DbContext will need to wait for EF to initialize its models. The bigger and more complex the DbContext is, the longer this can take. With a web application this will happen whenever the application pool recycles, which can include situations where the site is set up to preserve resources when idle. (Idle timeout)
Something like your initializer, or simply executing a simple query like:
using var context = new CodisContext();
context.Table.Any();

... when your app pool starts is enough to trigger this first run warm up cost. (I.e. just before app.Run())
Alternatively if you have a large, complex schema to use you can consider splitting it into smaller bounded DbContexts where each is responsible for a key area within the application. Smaller contexts can use simplified representations of tables if they don't need the full gambit of information which can be simpler and faster to work with.
As for returning a single field, or sub-set of fields from an entity, leverage projection to build efficient queries. Your example was possibly just a simple demo query, but if you have code that is interested in just retrieving some information from a record or records:
var variable = await context.Table
    .Where(v => v.Id == id)
    .Select(v => v.Field)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(); 

return variable ?? DefaultValue;

The difference between your example and the above is that in your case you would be executing a query to retrieve an entire record from the database when you are only concerned with one column. That entity will also be added to EF's tracking cache unnecessarily. This should only be done where you want to update entities so that you can make changes to that entity and call SaveChanges() letting EF build an appropriate UPDATE statement. For a simple read operation, the above query will just build an SQL statement to retrieve the single desired column if found. On larger tables with lots of potentially large columns this can make a very noticeable difference in performance and resource usage.

Simple access to property context.Model is enough to initialise model.

My context, luckily, is simple for this application as it is the first my team and I develop with this framework.
So if I did understand it all, it's good to have an initializer because the first query will always take more time to being executed due to the initialization of EF models.
And yes, the query was just an example, I have to make more deeply searcher to understand how EF queries work, but thanks for the code snippet, I will probably use it.
Of course, thanks for answering my question!
